# How do I find a path for every leaf node in a tree?

Tags: depth-first-search, tree-traversal, adjacency-list

I am using the adjacency lists for storing the tree, I want a path for every leaf node from the root node.

Comment: I am trying to build a function which returns an adjacency list containing paths for every leaf node in tree.

Comment: I will pass the adjacency list i.e., tree structure and array named visited of bool type.

Comment: Read in the [help cnter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What did you try exactely? Can you Show your efforts up to now?

Comment: input is ?   expected output ?  see [MCVE]